# Revert to official Android from Cyanogenmod

Tags: rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery, rom, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I have installed CyanogenMod 10.1.x on my Note 2, but I find it very unstable and it often goes on a reboot loop.

I use ClockworkMod recovery.

I would rather work with a stock android at this point.

Questions:

1. Since I have ClockworkMod recovery, I presume I can use it to flash the "official" ROM? Is this correct?
2. Can someone point me to the official stock android from Samsung?

Comment: Have you seen [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use CWM to flash the official ROM. As Izzy linked, [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) is our guide to finding ROMs for devices. In particular, you can find stock Samsung ROMs easily on [SamMobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/1/): there are different ROMs for each particular type of Note 2 and each country, so be sure to pick the right one for your device and location.

Also, it may be worth sticking with Cyanogenmod. Many new users don't appreciate how great the difference is between a nightly/snapshot build and a stable release. If you've been using a nightly or a beta, and a release candidate or stable release is available for your device, you might want to try that out before going back to stock. At the very least, you might consider filing a bug report for the boot loop you've observed. If nobody reports it, it may never be fixed.